# Log postgres query messages

Tags: windows, postgresql, logging

How can I write the query result messages, which inform the user that the query was successful or not and the number of affected records, to log file in PostgreSQL.

I have tried to change log_statement to 'all' and log_min_duration_statement to 0 but all I get is the query text.

Is it possible to redirect those messages to log file in a Windows OS?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: There must be a way :) I hope

Answer (score 0):

you can use [GET DIAGNOSTICS](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) for that.. And if you are a superuser, you can save result to a file...

```
create table tablename(version int);
insert into tablename select 9;
do
$$
declare 
 rc text;
begin
  update tablename set version=version where false;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
  raise info '%',' changed: '||rc;

  update tablename set version=version where true;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
  raise info '%',' changed: '||rc;

  raise info '%','If you are superuser you can save result to a file...';
  execute $e$copy(select '$e$||rc||$e$') to '/tmp/roes.log'$e$;
  raise exception '%','raiseing error to rollback changes';
end;
$$
;
```

and the result looks:

```
INFO:   changed: 0
INFO:   changed: 1
INFO:  If you are superuser you can save result to a file...
ERROR:  raiseing error to rollback changes

********** Error **********

ERROR: raiseing error to rollback changes
SQL state: P0001
```